# How to print the position of each value in a table column using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick jQuery question. Columns in my table represent a racers split time in a race. I want to compare the split time of one racer to the split time of another. For example, I have 3 racers with split times of 3 seconds, 4 seconds and 2 seconds respectively.

In the table cell next to each time, I'd like to output the position compared to other racers like so: 3 seconds (2), 4 seconds (3), and 2 seconds (1).

I'm sure it is a simple matter of adding each split time to an array, then iterating over each and printing the position. However I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this problem.

Here's a jsfiddle table as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hYvdp/

Comment: Can you post a demo table on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and link it here?

Comment: I would suggest doing this in your backend code if possible.

Comment: sure thing. Here's the table, and edited the original question to include it there as well. http://jsfiddle.net/hYvdp/

Answer (score 1):

If you have this html:

```
<table cellspacing='5' border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Race 1 time</td>
        <td>Race 2 time</td>
        <td>Race 3 time</td>
    </tr>
        <tr id='time'>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr id='position'>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you could do something like this to calculate position:

```
var racers= []
$('#time td').each(function(){
    var racer = {};
    racer['idx'] = $(this).index();
    racer['time'] =   $(this).text();
    racers.push(racer);
 });
racers.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.time > b.time){
        return 1;
    }else if(a.time < b.time){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

var position = 1;
for (i =0; i<racers.length; i++){
    var idx = racers[i].idx;
    $('#position td:eq('+idx+')').html('Position :'+position);
    position++;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XcpNw/

The third rows has the position that is calculate dinamically: you could attach the same behaviour to a function or to the response of an ajax call

Comment: this seems close, however I want to print the value of the position right next to the actual time. I've been playing with your solution here but I still can't seem to implement it how I want. What would you recommend?